# (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm getting the following error when running a AI Platform training job:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field: master_config.accelerator_config Error: Attaching 1 NVIDIA_TESLA_T4(s) on VM type n1-highcpu-32 is not supported.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Attaching 1 NVIDIA_TESLA_T4(s) on VM type n1-highcpu-32 is not supported.
    field: master_config.accelerator_config
```

config.yaml

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: n1-highcpu-32
  masterConfig:
    acceleratorConfig:
      count: 1
      type: NVIDIA_TESLA_T4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `n1-highcpu-32` you can choose 2 or 4 `NVIDIA Tesla T4` GPUs

Please verify the combination of Compute Engine and Accelerator [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-gpus)